# Can the value of std::chrono::system_clock::time_point change based on the timezone?

Tags: c++11

I have been writing unit tests for a class in our codebase that basically converts date, time values from `std::string` to `std::chrono::time_point` and vice versa, for different kinds of timestamps (yyyy-mm-dd , hh:mm:ss.ms etc).

One way I tried to test whether a `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point` returned by a function in our codebase as the same as one created in the unit tests was to do something like this -

```
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point m_TimePoint{}; // == Clock's epoch
auto foo = convertToString(n_TimePoint); //foo is std::string
auto bar = getTimePoint(foo);
ASSERT_EQ(m_TimePoint, bar);
```

This was on Ubuntu , now the constructor should return a time point as UTC Jan 1 00:00:00 1970. Now when I used `ctime()` to see the textual representation of the epoch it returned Dec 31 19:00:00 1969. I was puzzled and checked that EST(my system timezone) is equal to UTC-5.

Once I created the object as -

```
std::chrono::duration d{0};
d += std::chrono::hours(5);
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point m_TimePoint{d}; //== clock epoch + 5 hours
```

All worked fine.

My question is it possible for the system clock epoch to be adjusted based on the system timezone?

Answer (score 5):

There's two answers to this question, and I'll try to hit both of them.

`system_clock` was introduced in C++11, and its epoch was left unspecified.  So the technical answer to your question is:  yes, it is possible for the `system_clock` epoch to be adjusted based on the system timezone.

But that's not the end of the story.

There's only a few implementations of `system_clock`, and all of them model [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).  [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) is a measure of time duration since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, excluding leap seconds.  It is not dependent on the system timezone.

The C++20 spec standardizes this existing practice.

So from a practical standpoint, the answer to your question is: no, it is not possible for the `system_clock` epoch to be adjusted based on the system timezone.

One thing that could be tripping you up is that `system_clock` typically counts time in units finer than milliseconds.  It varies from platform to platform, and you can inspect what it is with `system_clock::duration::period::num` and `system_clock::duration::period::den`.  These are two compile-time integral constants that form a fraction, `n/d` which describes the length of time in seconds that `system_clock` is measuring.  For Ubuntu my guess would be this forms the fraction `1/1'000'000'000`, or `nanoseconds`.

You can get `milliseconds` (or whatever unit you want) out of `system_clock::time_point` with:

```
auto tp = time_point_cast<milliseconds>(system_clock::now());
```

Comment: Great answer! It's an honor to have my first C++ question to be answered by none other than Howard Hinnant! Thank You.